# Why does printing ch[1] give 2?

Tags: c, arrays, output, union

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
    union a
    {
        int i;
        char ch[2];
    };
    union a z = { 512 };
    printf("%d %d %d", z.i, z.ch[0], z.ch[1]);
 }
```

Output:

```
512 0 2
```

Why does printing `ch[1]` give `2`?

Comment: What would you expect the answer to be?

Comment: First of all you need to learn about [*binary numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number). Then you need to learn about [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). And of course how [unions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union) work.

Comment: What system / compiler are you using?

Comment: 512 = 2*256 + 0

Comment: Also note that on just about all PC-type computers sold the last couple of decades, the size of `int` is four bytes.

Comment: I think we need some sort of "type punning and endianess" canonical dupe. These questions are quite common.

Answer (score 1):

as you know, in a union all members start from the same place in memory.
so `ch[2]` starts from the same place as `i`. 512 = 0x00000200. So, in little endian, the first byte is `00` and the second is `02`.

Answer (score 0):

Your union has 4 bytes, and is assigned with 512, meaning you have

```
00:00:00:00-00:00:00:00-00:00:00:10-00:00:00:00
```

since 512 is a one with 9 zeros after it.

From here it's pretty easy to understand your prints.

As @Some programmer dude commented, this is due to how binary numbers look like + endianness.